# Final variable initialization in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, initialization

I understand this piece of code, It prints out: 0,4:

```
class A{
   A() {  print();   }
   void print() { System.out.println("A"); }
}
class B extends A{
   int i =   4;
   public static void main(String[] args){
      A a = new B();
      a.print();
   }
   void print() { System.out.println(i); }
}
```

I don't understand if `int = 4` is changed to `final int = 4` why does it print 4,4? Why does final get initialized before?

```
class A{
   A() {  print();   }
   void print() { System.out.println("A"); }
}
class B extends A{
  final int i =   4;
   public static void main(String[] args){
      A a = new B();
      a.print();
   }
   void print() { System.out.println(i); }
}
```

Can anyone explain how initialization goes in this example?

Comment: This code is a bad inheritance example because you should never call a non private method from within an constructor. This can rise many sorts of unexpected behavior where the one shown is just the tip of the iceberg...

Comment: @Timothy Truckle - you downvoted my question? This question is part of OCA certification prep tests... It is not mine idea. Why downvote?

Comment: *"you downvoted my question?"* NO! I just stated that this is a bad example for inheritace.

Comment: I don't understand why my question is down voted :(

Comment: OT:  *"I don't understand why my question is down voted"* neither me. but don't take it personal, maybe someone needed a downvote for her next badge...

Answer (score 0):

Here `i` of class `B` is class variable which is initialized on execution constructor(i variable int memory is allocated and initialized default data).

Any final variable can be initialized either of below options.

- while declaring a variable `final int i=4;`
  so here after execution of constructor memory is allocated and initialized with value assigned. to verify this.

  B(){
   print();
  }
  this will display : 4 as it initialized with final value.
- we can initialize the final value in constructor as below

  final int i;
  B(){
  i=4;
  }